# Calcular tiempo entre dos fechas: horas, minutos y segundos

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando el cálculo de un rango de días entre dos fechas con horas, minutos y segundos de la siguiente manera:

```
function calcularDiasAusencia(fechaIni, fechaFin)
{
var fecha1 = new   Date(fechaIni.substring(0,4),fechaIni.substring(5,7),fechaIni.substring(8,10));
var fecha2 = new Date(fechaFin.substring(0,4),fechaFin.substring(5,7),fechaFin.substring(8,10));
var diasDif = fecha2.getTime() - fecha1.getTime();
var dias = Math.round(diasDif/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

document.getElementById('diasAusentismo').value =  dias+1;

}
```

Donde **fechaIni** es 2016-10-31 20:14:31 y **fechaFin** es 2016-11-03 20:14:35, contando desde el 31 de octubre hasta el 3 de noviembre deberían haber 4 días pero el sistema me muestra solo 3 de igual manera me sale el cálculo malo haciendolo de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puede generar el error para que la función esté arrojando valores incorrectos?

Comment: Entre el 2016-10-31 20:14:31 y el 2016-11-03 20:14:35, solo hay 72 horas de diferencia, 4320 minutos, es decir 3 días. igual en el otro ejemplo ya que Septiembre solo tiene 30 días, tal ves no entendí bien la pregunta.

Comment: Probá con esta fórmula para sacar la cantidad de dias..`Math.floor((Fecha2 - Fecha1) / (1000*60*60*24))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que los meses en la función date van del 0 al 11 y estas mirando fechas equivocadas. El 2016-10-31 es el 1 de diciembre y el 2016-11-03 es el 3 de diciembre. La solución seria restarle uno a los meses pasados como parámetros a la función Date.

Puedes verlo todo en funcionamiento en este enlace de jsfiddle

[enlace de jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yojose/tf0bduh3/5/)

Comment: En la [documentación de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) viene explicado que los meses se representan del 0 al 11.

Answer (score 3):

El resultado de la resta ambas fechas es correcto. El error es que **el día de salida (`Fecha Inicio`) no esta siendo contemplado**, por lo que te estaría faltando sumar un día mas.

> **Por ejemplo**: del `2016-09-30` al `2016-10-01`, hay exactamente `1` día. Pero en para tu caso debería ser `2`, ya que el `2016-09-30` también va a estar ausente.

Prueba hacer el calculo así:

```js
function calcularDiasAusencia(fechaIni, fechaFin) {
  var diaEnMils = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      desde = new Date(fechaIni.substr(0, 10)),
      hasta = new Date(fechaFin.substr(0, 10)),
      diff = hasta.getTime() - desde.getTime() + diaEnMils;// +1 incluir el dia de ini
  return diff / diaEnMils;
}

document.getElementById('calcular').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('dias').innerText = calcularDiasAusencia(
    document.getElementById('fechaIni').value,
    document.getElementById('fechaFin').value
  );
});
```

```html
Desde: <input id="fechaIni" placeholder="yyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" value="2016-09-30 07:30:00" /><br>
Hasta: <input id="fechaFin" placeholder="yyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" value="2016-10-03 07:30:00" /><br>
<button type="button" id="calcular">Calcular</button><br>
Total días ausente: <span id="dias"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para situaciones que involucren cálculos con fechas y horas yo siempre recomiendo [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), p ej:

```
var fecha1 = moment("2016-09-30 07:30:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
var fecha2 = moment("2016-10-03 07:30:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

var diff = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'd'); // Diff in days
console.log(diff);

var diff = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'h'); // Diff in hours
console.log(diff);
```

Véase un [ejemplo completo](http://jsbin.com/zosugedoxi/edit?html,js,console).

Nótese que entre 2016-09-30 y 2016-09-30 hay CERO días, no un día. Es posible que lo que quieres obtener no es el tiempo *entre* dos fechas, sino el *tamaño del intervalo* definido por dos fechas. Eso es tan sencillo como sumar 1 al resultado (o redondear a la alza en caso de que el intervalo no sea de días completos).

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la solución que encontré, siguiendo el consejo de IvanSanchez.

```
function calcuTiempo(){
    var fini=$("#fechaFallaEstad").val();
    var ffin=$("#fechaSoluEstad").val();
    var hini=$("#horaFallaEstad").val();
    var hfin=$("#horaSoluEstad").val();
    var ini= fini+" "+hini;
    var fin= ffin+" "+hfin;
    var fecha1 = moment(ini, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
var fecha2 = moment(fin, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

var diff = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'h'); // Diff in days
var min= diff*60;
var diff1 = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'm')-min; // Diff in hours
    $("#timeRespEstad").val(diff+":"+diff1);

}
```